# Zend REST controller with Backbonejs

Tags: zend-framework, rest, backbone.js

Here is what iam planning to do :

I have a simple form and iam using BackboneJS.I want to make an AJAX request to check if username exisits or not.(Jquery ajax is much simpler,but iam told to do so).Iam using  [this article.](http://www.techchorus.net/create-restful-applications-using-zend-framework)So i created a controller called ArticleController :

```
namespace Album\Controller;
use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractRestfulController;
class ArticleController extends AbstractRestfulController{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        echo "Working";
    }
}
```

In my module.config file i added to the array invokables  :

> 'Album\Controller\Article' => 'Album\Controller\ArticleController',

(iam extending the zend skeleton application that they have build on the zend website).

So the problems iam facing :

1. when i goto

> http:// zf2-tutorials/album

iam able to load the application (skeleton built on website), but if i do

> http:// zf2-tutorials/article

it says page not found ! ? Should echo **Working** / What am i doing wrong/missing out
2.Is this the right approach what iam doing for making ajax request ?

Thank you

Comment: Are you mixing ZF1 and ZF2? I suggest you use only ZF2.

Comment: @Maks3w iam using ZF2 only , instead of zend_rest_controller here i used AbstractRestfulController

Comment: @Maks3w can you please suggest a tutorial to learn rest on Zend >

Comment: ZendRest is deprecated in ZF2 instead use Zend\Http. I don't know any tutorial about this right now but if you take a search sure you find some